# .Net MAUI WebAuthenticator CallbackUrl for social logins

Tags: azure-ad-msal, .net-maui, webauthenticator

I'm following  [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?tabs=android) to setup authenticating with social logins using MSAL and Web Authenticator. The example call looks like this:

```
WebAuthenticatorResult authResult = await WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(
    new Uri("https://example.com/mobileauth/Microsoft"),
    new Uri("myapp://"));
```

But **what should the second URI parameter be?** In the guide it says:

> The URI the flow is expected to ultimately call back to, that is registered to your app.

So how do I register a URI like that to my app?? I've tried following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication) and have 'registered' my app in azure active directory but facebook/google etc won't accept urls of the form "myapp://" as valid redirect URIs... What am I missing?

**Update**
So the first half of the flow is working but I keep getting errors from the OAuth providers (the green highlight in the diagram isn't working).
[image: Diagram]

This from Google:
[image: Google]

And this from Facebook:
[image: FB]

But I've added all these valid callback URLs:
[image: urls]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of it thanks to this old Xamarin issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1224#issuecomment-618192336

You have to set the "CallbackPath" property in the API config like so:

```
.AddGoogle(g => { 
     g.ClientId = "{Client ID}"; 
     g.ClientSecret = "{Client Secret}"; 
     g.CallbackPath = "/mobileauth"; //mobileauth is api controller 
     g.SaveTokens = true; })
```

And then tell the provider of that redirect e.g. adding "https://{API-URL}/mobileauth" in google console.

Comment: Any chance for a full example?   What url did you send?  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth doesn't seem to be correct.  Where exactly is this "API config" you mention?  I am getting required parameter missing response type

Comment: The 'API Config' is the Program.cs file in my API project referred to as 'ASP.NET Backend' in the first picture of my original question. You don't need to specify the google end point like that, the WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync() knows the oauth provider endpoints already. You tell it where to call back to on your own server. Check the first guide i linked for a full example.

Comment: Ahh see there's the issue this question was tagged MAUI not asp.net.  I was hoping you had a solution for android authorization with Maui.

Comment: Hi, currently stuck on this exact issue with facebook SSO. Just to check @Jimmy, when you passed in the "mobileauth" parameter into Google in your example above, should that not have been  /mobileauth/Google ?

Comment: I think that would work as well, have you tried both with and without?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that example is broken.
The second URI parameter represents where your app is listening to get the authentication result.

Actually, `myapp://` is not a valid URI. You should try with something like `myapp://callback`.

Comment: How do I configure where my app is listening since it's an app and can't be reached by normal web requests?

Comment: To handle your callback URI you need some platform-specific setup.
See [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?tabs=android#get-started)

Comment: that's the exact link I'm referencing in the question

Comment: I know. That link brings you to the document's section ("Get Started") where how to configure your app to listen to `myapp` scheme is explained for each platform

Comment: I'm back on this 5 months later and still can't get it to work. I can't add a url like myapp://callback to the valid callback urls. Facebook, Google etc require the url start with http or https