# How would I open a browser and listen for the redirect in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-authentication, maui

I'm creating a .NET MAUI app and would like to integrate Firebase authentication. I'm using the FirebaseAuthentication.net NuGet package for interacting with the API, which offers me a SignInWithRedirect method. The method passes a URL to a delegate function, which according to the docs, has to open the web browser with the url, and somehow return a redirect back to MAUI. The only way of opening a browser I've found for MAUI is the following:

```
await client.SignInWithRedirectAsync(FirebaseProviderType.Google, async uri =>
{
 -->   return await Browser.Default.OpenAsync(uri, BrowserLaunchMode.External);
});
```

However, the problem is this only returns a boolean stating if the browser was succesfully opened or not. Is there another way how I could achieve what I'd like to do in MAUI?

EDIT: Added a code sample with WebAuthenticator (which results in a "Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared" error in the browser)
The login service with Firebase initialization:

```
public LoginService(IHttpService httpService)
    {
        var config = new FirebaseAuthConfig
        {
            ApiKey = API_KEY,
            AuthDomain = DOMAIN,
            Providers = new FirebaseAuthProvider[]
            {
                new EmailProvider(),
                new FacebookProvider(),
                new GoogleProvider()
            },
        };

        client = new FirebaseAuthClient(config);
        
        _httpService = httpService;
    }
```

The actual function that inits the authenticator:

```
public async Task<bool> GoogleLogin()
    {
        try
        {
            await client.SignInWithRedirectAsync(FirebaseProviderType.Google, async uri =>
            {
                var options = new WebAuthenticatorOptions
                {
                    Url = new Uri(uri),
                    CallbackUrl = new Uri("com.companyname.myappname.maui://callback/"),
                };


                var res = await WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(options);

                return "";
            });

            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The activity added to the Android platform based on MS docs instructions:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;

namespace YourNameSpace;

[Activity(NoHistory = false, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
              Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
              DataPath = "/callback/",
              DataScheme = "com.companyname.myappname.maui")]
public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, do you want a feature similar to the following?

[Net MAUI WebAuthenticator CallbackUrl for social logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641363/net-maui-webauthenticator-callbackurl-for-social-logins)

You can set the `CallbackPath` property in the API config like so:

```
.AddGoogle(g => { 
     g.ClientId = "{Client ID}"; 
     g.ClientSecret = "{Client Secret}"; 
     g.CallbackPath = "/mobileauth"; //mobileauth is api controller 
     g.SaveTokens = true; })
```

Comment: Sort of, but I'm not using an API, only MAUI so this approach doesn't work. I've done a similar thing with the WebAuthenticator in MAUI, but am getting a "Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared" error after signing in. Think it has something to do with the callback URL. Would you happen to know what the problem could be?

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post relative code snippets or a basic demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Comment: Hey, just added a few code snippets if you'd have any time to try and help me out as I still have this issue...