# Unable to integrate Google and Apple login in .NET MAUI project

Tags: google-signin, maui, apple-sign-in

I'm working on a .NET MAUI project and I'm trying to integrate both Google and Apple login functionality. However, I'm encountering some issues and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

I've added the necessary packages to my project (e.g. Google.Apis.Auth and Xamarin.Auth).
I've created OAuth 2.0 credentials for both Google and Apple in their respective developer consoles.
I've tried following tutorials and documentation, but I'm still not able to get the login to work.

I am working on .net 6 framework but Xamarin.Auth does not support for android platform

Can anyone provide some guidance or point me in the right direction? Specifically, I'm looking for information on how to:

Authenticate the user using Google or Apple login
Retrieve the user's information (e.g. email address, name) from the authentication provider
Store the authentication token securely
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried two different approaches to implementing login functionality in my .NET MAUI project: web authentication and Xamarin.Auth. With web authentication, I used the built-in WebView control to display the Google and Apple login screens and authenticate the user. However, I ran into some issues with handling the redirect URL

Comment: Can this case about [.Net MAUI WebAuthenticator CallbackUrl for social logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641363/net-maui-webauthenticator-callbackurl-for-social-logins) help you?